# Annotate subclass's method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, pycharm

Suppose I have a Mixin class `Mixin`, and a method `a` in this class uses another method 
`b` which will be in another `Base` class. I want to annotate `b` in class `Mixin` so that I can take the advantages of inspection.

The real usage is multiple inherition. I create a mixin for `tornado.web.RequestHandler`, and the subclass could inherit both `RequestHandler` and `Mixin` to get some useful functions.

As far as I know, I can annotate `b` as `Callable`, but I cannot annotate its signature.

```
class Base

    def b():
        # do something

class Mixin:
    b: Callable  # not enough, losing signature.
    #b: RequestHandler.b  # not work, still losing signature.
    def a():
        # call b here.

class subclass(Base, Mixin):
    pass
```

BTW, I'm using Pycharm.

Comment: Are you trying to annotate the subclass method or attribute?

Comment: @RamazanPolat It isn't related to subclass but only baseclass. I need to use function `b` in function `a`, and I hope pycharm can inspect `b`'s signature while I am writing `a`.

Comment: AFAIU, in Base class, a method named A will call another method called B. The method B will be defined in a subclass of Base. Is this correct?

Comment: Do you mean that `b` in subclasses could have different signatures or they are always same?

Comment: Guys, see my update. Sorry for confusion.